# Scriptlets in jsp

Tags: jsp, struts2

Hi everyone I was going through a concept that if a variable is created inside scriptlet in jsp its scope will be the entire jsp page. I tried writing the folowing code.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%! String[] parts= null;
String sm=null;%>

<s:iterator value="ServiceManagement"><br/><% sm=%><s:property/>
<% parts=sm.split(":");  %>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<s:checkbox fieldvalue=<%= parts[1] %>" theme="simple" name="service_management"/>
<%= parts[0] %></s:iterator>
```

I am geting an error at "<%= parts[0] %>" saying " Syntax error, insert ";" to complete 
     Statement" "Array constants can only be used in 
     initializers"

Plz help me out I am new to java.

Comment: Scriptlet is always not a recommended way to write jsps. Logics should be separated from presentation.

Comment: Do ALL that things in your Action; print the results in JSP using Struts2 tags; do not use scriptlet ever again, when possible (99.9% of the time IT IS possible).

Answer (score 0):

```
<% sm=%>
```

This statement will not compile. you should rather write `<% sm="abc";%>`

Note that the assignemnt is given to the `sm` variable and the statement is completed with a semi-colon `;` Earlier you were making that statement incomplete without assigning anything and then you were writing new statement.

When you write this in your jsp 
`<% sm=%><% parts= sm.split(":"); %>`

It will be converted into something like this:

```
sm=
parts= sm.split(":");
```

You see it won't compile.

Comment: earlier my question want complete..plz see this now and help me out if you can.